# $watch on directive with isolated scope for nested object as property from crossfilter

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, angularjs-directive, crossfilter

I have created a directive with isolated scope, element, and am using those values passed in to build d3/dc charts. So I have some data that is put through crossfilter on the $scope, so that the directive attributes can read it. Then I am pulling into the directive and logging scope shows it fine, however I can't access the nested object specifically/directly without getting undefined.

within the controller:

```
var data = [{
    "player": "Player A",
        "team": "New York",
        "hits": 200
}, {
    "player": "Player B",
        "team": "New York",
        "hits": 225
}, {
    "player": "Player C",
        "team": "New York",
        "hits": 1
}, {
    "player": "Player D",
        "team": "San Francisco",
        "hits": 268
}, {
    "player": "Player E",
        "team": "San Francisco",
        "hits": 22
}, {
    "player": "Player F",
        "team": "Seattle",
        "hits": 2
}, {
    "player": "Player G",
        "team": "Seattle",
        "hits": 25
}]
$scope.ndx = crossfilter(data);
$scope.playerDim = $scope.ndx.dimension(function (d) {
     return d.player;
});

$scope.playerGrp = $scope.playerDim.group().reduceSum(function (d) {
   return d.hits;
});
```

html

```
    <my-chart id="someChart"
                   chart-type="pieChart"
                   height="200"
                   width="200"
                   dimension="playerDim"
                   group="playerGrp" />
```

directive:

```
myApp.directive('myChart', ['chartFactory' function(chartFactory) {
    return {
       restrict: 'E',
       scope = {
          chartType: "@",
          height: "@",
          width: "@",
          dimension: "=",
          group: "="
       },
       link: function(scope, elem, attr) {
          console.log(scope) // shows the dimension object as a property on the object just fine
          console.log(scope.dimension) // undefined
       }
    };
}])
```

My guess is that the function hasn't really set the object there when I console.log it, though it shows it there (misleading). I have tried $watch, $timeout, etc and nothing seems to allow me to get at that nested object.

Can anyone please help me understand what is happening here?

Comment: Likely something asynchronous going on inside `crossfilter(data)`. An object in console has inheritance and is not a snapshot. Create a demo that reproduces problem

Comment: Is it  really the code that you copied  from edior?Several errors are there.

Comment: As @charlietfl mentioned, it is likely that there is an async operation going on. The `scope` is an object that you are logging(and it will log fine) but the `dimension` property on this object is created by some async operation and at the time of logging it is not populated and that's why you are getting `undefined` as the value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using a `$watch`

```
link: function(scope, elem, attr) {      
  scope.$watch('dimension', function(nVal, oVal) {
    if (nVal) {
      console.log('dimension=', scope.dimension);
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: thanks very much. I was missing something pretty obvious in the $watch....long night.